# How to assign variable to be left over choice from array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have code that picks an array index that isn't equal to two others. I have some fake code written out that explains what I want to be done.

```py
list = [1,2,3]

choice != list[0] and list [2]

print(choice)
```

In this case, I would want the code to understand I don't want to select index 0 or 2 which means it will assign the variable `choice` to `2` because it is the only item left.

The result I seek:

> 2

Comment: your explanation isn't clear. Why can't you do `list[1]`?

Comment: whats output of `list = [1,2,3,1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like :

```
choices = [x for x in list if x not in [list[0], list[2]]]
print(choices[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Provided there are no duplicates this works fine.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
choice = list(filter(lambda x: x != arr[0] and x!=arr[2], arr))
```